# How to notify Windows about changes in Desktop settings?

Tags: windows, winapi, system, messaging, getsystemmetrics

How to notify Windows system that some appearance settings has been changed by my program?

I'm working with:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop -> FontSmoothing + FontSmoothingType

What is a standard way? Maybe there is some message. Where to send it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't modify the registry directly.

Instead, call the [`SystemParametersInfo` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947%28VS.85%29.aspx):

```
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETFONTSMOOTHING, TRUE, NULL, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
```

Comment: +1 Really, use the API, the registry is implementation detail